# Grouping Rows ("conditional copy") from different tables in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to group the students of some classes into different groups at school using LibreOffice Calc.

I already have tables for all classes, where I entered the group (1-3) of every student:

[image: ClassA]

What I LibreOffice want to do now, is to copy all students of all classes, which are in group 1 (group 2, group 3, ...), into one new table (Group1). Then, I have one list with the students for every group.

In this example, it would be Name1 and Name6.

I searched the web for hours and played around a lot without success.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You mention in a comment that you have multiple tables for different classes.  I'd recommend keeping all the classes in one table - add a column "Class" to the table.  Then maybe look into VLOOKUP.  See [VLOOKUP questions and answers](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=46746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the data cells A1:B8;
2. Menu `Data` -> `Standard Filter...`
3. In the standard filter window, set the filter properties as follows:
   [image]

   1. Field Name: Group; Condition: =, Value: 1 (or select from dropdown);
   2. Click on `Options`
   3. Select "`Copy results to`"; enter the target: `$Group1.$A$1`
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: That's great --- thank you!! I didn't get the idea of using filters for doing that. But one more question: There are students of group 1 in more than one table (classA, classB, ...). So I need to apply the filter to multiple areas. Is this possible? I could first create a temporary table and copy all students to it and then apply the filter, but this seems to be a workaround for me ...

Comment: AFAIK, you can't define one filter for non-contiguous cell ranges. So, in your case, you would have to use a workaround like using a temporary table.

Comment: Is it possible to apply more than one filter to an area?

Comment: @dawu Have you considered setting these tables up in Base instead of Calc?  Then you could write multiple queries (queries are kindof like the database version of filters) to show each group of the information you wanted.

Comment: @Lyrl It's a typical example of "I just need a table" but now ended up in "create a database". In my case, it would be easier to do it with a workaround, because I only need this document once a year and it would be to much effort to set up a database ...